# What is the most efficient way to replace NaNs in multiple columns based on a default value column?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame like

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame( { 'val1': [1,np.nan,3], 'val2': [np.nan,5,6], 'val3': [7,np.nan,8], 'default': [ 42,43,44 ] } )
```

i.e.

```
   default  val1  val2  val3
0       42     1   NaN     7
1       43   NaN     5   NaN
2       44     3     6     8

[3 rows x 3 columns]
```

I would like to have each NaN replaced by it's default value given in the respective row in the column 'default'.

I could do it columnwise in a for loop using DataFrame.fillna

```
for col in [ 'val1', 'val2' ]:
    df[ col ] = df[ col ].fillna( df['default'] )
```

which yields the desired result

```
   default  val1  val2  val3
0       42     1    42     7
1       43    43     5    43
2       44     3     6     8
```

I wonder if there is a non-for-loop and presumably a more efficient solution? My DataFrame could contain several hundreds of columns and several ten-thousands of rows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Be sure to use double brackets to indicate `df[['default']]` is a DataFrame instead of a Series, otherwise your results won't match the expected output.

```
>>> df.fillna(df[['default']].values)
   default  val1  val2  val3
0       42     1    42     7
1       43    43     5    43
2       44     3     6     8
```

In pandas 16.1+, you need to pass a Series for each column which can be built using a dictionary comprehension.

```
defaults = df['default']
>>> df.fillna({col: defaults for col in df})
   default  val1  val2  val3
0       42     1    42     7
1       43    43     5    43
2       44     3     6     8
```

Comment: with pandas version 0.16.1 `df.fillna(df[['default']].values)` raises the exception `ValueError: invalid fill value with a <type 'numpy.ndarray'>`.

Answer (score 1):

since in pandas version 0.16.1 I cannot pass a numpy.ndarray to DataFrame.fillna() (see my comment on the answer of Alexander)

Instead I could pass a DataFrame to df.fillna(). The documentation  says, that this DataFrame specifies the value for each column. Therefore, I have to transpose df, fill the na, and transpose back

```
df.T.fillna(df['default']).T
```

So, it is even shorter. But is it also the most efficient?